# How to get 1.week.ago at 12pm with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need a week ago at 12pm in milliseconds for a chart.

Now i can do

```
1.week.ago.to_i * 1000
```

but this will always return the current time a week ago. How can i get 12pm (noon) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not see this the first time i read the docs.

There is a "at_noon" method.

```
1.week.ago.at_noon.to_i * 1000
```

Answer (score 2):

```
1.week.ago.change(hour: 12).to_i * 1000
```

Actually if you are using Rails 4.1 you could use:

```
1.week.ago.at_noon.to_i * 1000
```

according to [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-at_noon), although I'm on 4.0.4 so I haven't tested this

Comment: Thanks but there is a "at_noon" method.

Comment: Yes I know now; but it just came in at 4.1 which is why I didn't know about it.  I only just saw it in the API.

Comment: Doing + 12.hours would give an incorrect result twice a year in places observing daylight saving time.

Comment: @FrederickCheung excellent point - thank you.  I've changed my answer now to a different way to do it pre Rails 4.1

Comment: Heh lucky me, method just came on time :)